# How to serialize scala trait play 2.3.x?

Tags: json, scala, serialization, playframework-2.0, traits

Consider the following:

I have a trait plugin..

```
trait Plugin {val foo:String, val bar:String}
```

.. and 2 case classes plugOne and plugTwo!

```
case class PlugOne ( override val foo:String, override val bar:String, plugValOne:String ) extends Plugin

case class PlugTwo ( override val foo:String, override val bar:String, plugValTwo:String ) extends Plugin
```

Another case class..

```
case class PluginCol ( plugins:Seq[Plugin] )
```

.. stores a sequence of Plugins. 
Considering I have all the implicit formats for my case classes PlugOne and PlugTwo, how can I serialize my PluginCol since it has a sequence of Plugin trait (which has no apply/unapply method).
What I want to achieve is to write a json version of PluginCol to a mongoDB collection.

Is there any way to solve such an issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`Serialization` is conversion of `Objects` into a format that can be stored and can be used to reconstruct the object.

`Plugin` is a `trait`. You can not create an object of `Plugin`. To create `Seq[Plugin]`, you will create a `Sequence` of either `PlugOne` or `PlugTwo`.

```
scala> PluginCol(Seq(PlugTwo("s", "x", "z"), PlugOne("a","b","c")))
res7: PluginCol = PluginCol(List(PlugTwo(s,x,z), PlugOne(a,b,c)))

scala> res7.plugins
res9: Seq[Plugin] = List(PlugTwo(s,x,z), PlugOne(a,b,c))
```

As you can see, from the above code that `Seq[Plugin]` actually contains objects of case classes PlugOne and PlugTwo.

Considering from your question that you have all the implicit formats for your case classes `PlugOne` and `PlugTwo`, you should not have any problem to serialize the object.